# Kohana: Requested URL was Not Found

Tags: php, routes, kohana, kohana-3

So I'm trying to install and get running Kohana. I am very new to it and frameworks in general (though I have used CakePHP a little bit).

Anyways...in my bootstrap file I have this:

```
// GET PARAMS -- This basically splits domain.com/kohana/controller/action/param1/etc
// into: controller | action | param1 | etc
$requestURI = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$scriptName = explode('/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

    for($i= 0;$i < sizeof($scriptName);$i++){
      if ($requestURI[$i] == $scriptName[$i]){
         unset($requestURI[$i]);
      }
    }

    $param = array_values($requestURI);
    $controller = @ $param[0];
    $action = @ $param[1];
    $param1 = @ $param[2];
    $param2 = @ $param[3];
    $param3 = @ $param[4];
    $param4 = @ $param[5];
    $param5 = @ $param[6];
    $param6 = @ $param[7];
```

Now, I want to connect to my database and basically see if the first param aka $param[0] aka $controller is equal to one of my pages "categories" (corresponds to my categories_pages table). If it IS a category then I want to use the default "categories" controller otherwise, the controller should be whatever $param[0] is. This means if I go to domain.com/kohana/movies or domain.com/kohana/games it will display the categories controller otherwise domain.com/kohana/users will display the users controller.

```
$db = Database::instance();
$getiscategory  = DB::select('*')->from('categories_pages')->where('directory', '=', $controller)->execute();
$is_category = $getiscategory->count();

if($is_category){
$controller = "categories";
}

    $controller = (empty($controller)) ? 'index' : $controller;
    $action = (empty($action)) ? 'index' : $action;
```

What I wanted to accomplish above works. If I echo $is_category I see that the value 1 is returned when there is a category match and if I echo $controller, I see that "categories" is set to be the controller.

Here is my code for the actual routing method...

```
Route::set(
    'custom',
    '(<controller>(/<action>(/<param1>)(/<param2>(/<param3>(/<param4>(/<param5>(/<param6>)))))))'
    )->defaults(array(
    'controller' => $controller,
    'action'     => $action,
    'param1'     => $param1,
    'param2'     => $param2,
    'param3'     => $param3,
    'param4'     => $param4,
    'param5'     => $param5,
    'param6'     => $param6,
));
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure where it's routing to. As I mentioned $controller is returned previously as categories which is correct but yet I receive the error message "HTTP_Exception_404 [404]: The Requested URL $param[0] (movies or games, etc) was not found on this server."

Keep in mind I do not have a controller class for $param[0] if it matches a category because I want to use the "categories" controller class. If I go to domain.com/kohana/categories it works fine.

Anyone have any ideas/know a work-around?

**Addition #1**

I figured out that even though the categories controller is called and the correct action is called, it still is requiring the "shows" controller to display. I added a shows controller with the very basic info (template, content, etc) and it showed correctly. Is there a work around in the routing class to make the designated controller show? Like I said, I tell it what controller to go to and it acknowledges it but it doesn't actually go to it.

Comment: I am sorry to say this, but I think you are completely off with the code in your bootstrap. The reason to you use a framework is not have to do stuff like this. You can get all of the route segments (or params) with `$this->request->param()` in your action. 

http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing#request-parameters 

And for your actual problem with the routing read the documentation more and the answer from Lethargy. You could specify a route without  `<controller>` in your URI and set a default controller in `defaults()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating things I think. Also your code would force a limit of 6 parameters on every request.

I'll probably be easier to use two different routes, and if it doesn't match the first, then it can fall back to the second.

```
Route::set(
    'categories',
    '(<category>(/<action>(/<param1>)(/<param2>(/<param3>(/<param4>(/<param5>(/<param6>)))))))',
    array('category' => '(movies|games)')
    )->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'category',
        'action'     => 'index',
));
Route::set(
    'users',
    '<username>(/<action>(/<param1>)(/<param2>(/<param3>(/<param4>(/<param5>(/<param6>))))))'
    )->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action'     => 'index',
));
```

If you only have one or two categories you could build them into the regex string, with some caching of course.

Otherwise, [look up lambda routes](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing#lambdacallback-route-logic), they're the means by which you can have dynamic routes like this.